# Chrome removes "stacked tab" option?

Tags: google-chrome

When I opened up Chrome yesterday afternoon, the tabs of chrome becomes a lot of **"little mountains"**. And, can't find the "stacked tabs" setting in chrome://flags anymore.

Is the feature gone ??

Here's the current screen, it's so hard to know which the tabs are.... So bad!! Really bad!!

Is there anyway to config back to the stacked tab or to set the minimum width of the tab of chrome ??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately "stacked tabs" option was removed from latest Chrome.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=332077